# How can I destroy a block from afar?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing on the [PPCG Minecraft server](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24544/ppcg-minecraft-server) for a little while, and I've managed to build a fairly decent tower, but someone has decided to do this, right next to the top:

[image]

While I could build out and get it, I don't have a silk touch pickaxe, which means I'd have to make more glass, and I'd lose some resources due to the height as well.

Is there any way that I can destroy this block from afar? *Do note, I don't have command privileges.*

Comment: Is there any particular reason you'd need to break the glass to build a bridge over to it? What about mining out through those cobble blocks on the left of your screenshot?

Comment: It's besides the point of the question, but in addition to @gandalf's comment, couldn't you just make two more glass blocks? Is sand/glass rare for some reason?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of building a bridge you can also **build a pile**. Position yourself underneath the floating block and start placing blocks below you.

[image: Character standing on pile.]

After your done destroying the floating block start digging down till you reach the ground. This way you don't have to break any glass in your tower and you don't lose any resources beside some tool durability.

Comment: A refinement to this technique: make the pile out of sand. Start by digging a 2-block deep 3x3 pit (with the center intact) and fill it with water. Place a torch on the center of the pit and build your pile. When done, fall down to the water filled pit and destroy the first sand block.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard This does indeed saves you some tool durability but it takes a bit more preparation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to destroy a block from a distance, a TNT cannon could be used.
This would use more resources than just building a bridge to get there as every TNT takes 4 sand and you would need about 6 TNT per shot.  Right there that would be 24 glass without counting the other materials needed (gunpowder, redstone, etc.)

http://www.instructables.com/id/Minecraft-TNT-cannon/

Comment: Yeah, try hitting one block in air with a TNT cannon. Dirt bridge would be more convenient.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a TNT cannon(which would be rather inaccurate) would either A) Miss the block and waste resources B) Wreck his tower C) Backfire and wreck his tower

Comment: On the _upside_ though, it would be a fun activity for more experienced players